# How to check the value inside the SQL database in php

Tags: php, sql, if-statement, conditional-statements

```
<?php
    $email = $_SESSION['eemailid']; 
    $query1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM attendance where email='$email'");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query1))
    {
      $status = $row['status'];
    }
    if ($status =='IN')
    {
      echo "Success";
    }
      else 
    {
    echo "Failed"; 
    }
?>
```

This is my phd code. I have a database named attendance in that i need to find a user my using email. After finding the user i have column called status in SQL. If the value of the status inside the column is "IN". I need to show Success. If the value is "OUT" i need to show Failed. here i am using email as session to find the current user. Can u please help me to do..

Thank You in advance.

Comment: So what exactly is the problem? Are you getting an error? The wrong output?

Comment: What is wrong with that now?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_connect.asp

Comment: always showing Failed. If the data in Status is "IN" also

Comment: I Need to check the value inside the database.. If the success Column Have the data as "IN" i should so success else failed. But i am getting always failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way

```
 <?php
    $email = $_SESSION['eemailid']; 
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM attendance where email='"$email "'");
   $status="";
     while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
      $status = $row['status'];
    }
    if ($status =='IN')
    {
      echo "Success";
    }
      else 
    {
    echo "Failed"; 
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: I thought + operator is only used in Javascript. Dot is used in PHP or am I wrong?

Comment: I Need to check the value inside the database.. If the success Column Have the data as "IN" i should so success else failed. But i am getting always failed

Comment: Lol this code is again wrong

Comment: May i know what's the purpose of giving this = $status=" ";

Comment: variable scope to declaration

Comment: $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM attendance where email='$email' ");
   $status="";
     while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))

Comment: @SparkyBuddy it is change out if it help out then given vote and right mark

Answer (score 1):

Be sure you are connected to your database.
Be sure you have inserted correct data (username,password,ect.)

Please read this:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php

```
<?php
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');
if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo 'Connected successfully';
mysql_close($link);
?>
```

and then read this:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

```
<?php
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM attendance where email='%s'"), mysql_real_escape_string($email));
if (!$result){
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    if ($row['status'] =='IN'){
        echo "Success";
    }
    else {
        echo "Failed"; 
        }
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: I Need to check the value inside the database.. If the success Column Have the data as "IN" i should so success else failed. But i am getting always failed

Comment: here you go. edited.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure with your data in Database, but please double check follow these steps below:

1. $_SESSION['eemailid']; // eemailid or emailid? or email?
2. How many rows in your database with the column email equal to $email? What is the value of status column of the last row with email equal to $email? because your IF ELSE statement is out of WHILE loop

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $email = $_SESSION['eemailid']; 
    $query1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM attendance where email='$email'");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query1))
    {
      $status = $row['status'];
    }
    if ($status =='IN')
    {
      echo "Success";
    }
      else if ($status == "OUT") 
    {
    echo "Failed"; 
    } else { 
    echo "Error"
     }
?>
```

Use this code and tell us what happen. This could be a problem with your SQL query